# Azure Storage explorer download failed with success message?

Tags: windows, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I'm trying to download a file from azure storage explorer from azure blob container. But the download is getting failed with success msg with below error.

{

"name": "Error",

"message": "self signed certificate in certificate chain",

"stack": "Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain\n    at TLSSocket. (_tls_wrap.js:1088:38)\n    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)\n    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)\n    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)",

"code": "SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"

}

Can someone shed some light on this issue please ?

Thx,
Arun

Comment: What is the version of Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer?
Download the latest version from the following link and retry the operation.

http://www.storageexplorer.com/

Comment: Hi @VikranthS I'm using the version 0.9.2 downloaded from the link and same issue.

Answer (score 7):

**Error : Self-Signed Certificate in Certificate Chain ,Unable to retrieve child resources.**

Issue for me: I am attached with office proxy server. But Azure Storage Explorer is not using that proxy.

Solution:

> Azure Storage Explorer -> Edit -> Configure Proxy,
> **Source = No proxy**   "Changed to" **Use System proxy(preview)**

After making these changes; I am able access the resources.

Comment: This has helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> self signed certificate in certificate chain

**SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN** it indicates that Azure no longer know whether the received HTTPS message is tampered. You also could get the answer from [Azure Storage Explorer troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting).

**Root Cause :**

> **Error: Self-Signed Certificate in Certificate Chain**
>
> There are several reasons why you may encounter this error, and the most common two reasons are as follows:
>
> The app is connected through a “**transparent proxy**”, which means a server (such as your company server) is intercepting HTTPS traffic, decrypting it, and then encrypting it using a self-signed certificate.
>
> You are running an application, such as antivirus software, which is injecting a self-signed SSL certificate into the HTTPS messages that you receive.

**Solution:**

You can let Storage Explorer trust it.

> When Storage Explorer encounters one of the issues, it can no longer know whether the received HTTPS message is tampered. If you have a copy of the self-signed certificate, you can let Storage Explorer trust it. If you are unsure of who is injecting the certificate, follow these steps to find it:
>
> 1. Install Open SSL
>
>    - Windows (any of the light versions should be sufficient)
>    - Mac and Linux: should be included with your operating system
> 2. Run Open SSL
>
>    - Windows: open the installation directory, click /bin/, and then double-click openssl.exe.
>    - Mac and Linux: run openssl from a terminal.
> 3. Execute s_client -showcerts -connect microsoft.com:443
> 4. Look for self-signed certificates. If you are unsure which are self-signed, look for anywhere the subject ("s:") and issuer ("i:") are the same.
> 5. When you have found any self-signed certificates, for each one, copy and paste everything from and including -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- to -----END CERTIFICATE----- to a new .cer file.
>      Open Storage Explorer, click Edit > SSL Certificates > Import Certificates, and then use the file picker to find, select, and open the .cer files that you created.

---

If you cannot find any self-signed certificates using the above steps, contact Azure team through the feedback tool for more help